# iOS realtime location tracker like in uber?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3, real-time

I'm building an iOS app that needs access to the location of the two users: driver and passenger. This app will be quite similar to Uber app where the passenger requests for a driver nearby to pick him up and eventually track the location of the driver real time. I'm new with location based app, so I would like to ask for best approach to do this. So here's my algorithm so far:

- Passenger app requests for driver by sending his current location to
  the server
- Server queries the nearest driver and sends push notification message
  to the selected driver
- Driver receives the push notification message and sends confirmation 
  back to the server
- Server sends the details to the passenger
- Driver starts sending his location to the server (every 10secs) thru 
  REST API request
- Server sends the drivers location to the passenger thru push
  notification

Please suggest a better real time location tracker SDK because we can rely on APNS push notifications fully as they arent guaranteed. An moreover calling the API from the passenger application to update about the driver location is not a fruitful process as i think so . So please suggest any better alternative to this. Any ideas are welcomed .

Comment: I will suggest you to firebase realtime chat to send driver location to passenger (passenger app update location according to new message received(dont show that message ), no need to fetch driver location to server) and also firebase data synch for driver location to firebase.

Answer (score 2):

For real-time location I would suggest you try services like [realm](https://realm.io/products/realm-mobile-platform/) or [firebase](https://firebase.google.com/) to share both the passenger's location coordinates & even an array (if you want to display more than one vehicle) of driver location coordinates.